# Ajax suddenly not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i got this error in my console.and suddenly the selectOneMenu did not fire any listener when the value changes.im using primefaces-3.0.M2.jar.

```
    Unhandled by MetaTagHandler for type org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehavior
```

and this is my code in .xhtml file

```
    <p:ajax actionListener="#{innovationManager.innovationAreaListener}" event="change" update="frmInnovation" />
```

anyone got any clue about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p:ajax>` tag does not support the `actionListener` attribute. It should have been `listener`.

```
<p:ajax listener="#{innovationManager.innovationAreaListener}" event="change" update="frmInnovation" />
```

I wonder if you didn't omit some parts of the error message. The hint about the `actionListener` attribute should have been included in the exception message.

Comment: im afraid that's all the error message.changed to listener,and it work just fine.not sure whats the problem coz i was using actionListener all the time and it work until just now.thanks for helping

Comment: You're likely confusing it with command links/buttons. Further I'm not sure what you mean with "coz", I am not a native English speaker. Please try to write proper English and not to introduce some childish/SMS talk or something. This way all non-native English readers will understand you better.

Comment: i guess i mixed up with command links/button.and thanks for the advice.i type it without realizing it sometimes.